# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Ну(,)а так как меня считали своей..." — нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае **НУ** - частица, которая  служит для усиления последующего высказывания; то же, что «так, итак» (употребляется при подведении итогов); то же, что «допустим, положим». Интонационно (и знаками препинания) **не** отделяется от последующих слов. Сравните: *Ну а если любит, то и сам приедет, и гостей привезет.* (Ю. Домбровский, Факультет ненужных вещей).

Запятая не нужна: "*Ну а так как меня считали своей...*"